# Why is collection not being displayed using EditorForModel()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I would like a collection to be displayed using EditorForModel().

According to this [Blog from Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html) this should be a no brainer.  However, it just does not work for me.

The Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index() {

        var contact = new Contact() { FirstName = "Greg", LastName = "Gum", Age = 27 };
        contact.PhoneNumbers = new List<string>();
        contact.PhoneNumbers.Add("111");
        contact.PhoneNumbers.Add("222");
        return View(contact);
    }
```

The Class:

```
public class Contact
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public List<String> PhoneNumbers { get; set; } 

}
```

The View:

```
@model WebApplication33.Models.Contact

@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

This displays the other properties just fine, but not the collection.  How do I get the collection to display?  I have tried and tried to get this to work, as all the things I have read seem to say this should work just as the above.

Comment: you may need to define your own template for `DisplayFor` helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a re-usable template that will display the fields.

Create a folder called: /Views/YourController/DisplayTemplates

If the template needs to be shared across controllers: /Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates

Create a view in the DisplayTemplates folder called Contact. In that view display the four fields:

```
@model WebApplication33.Models.Contact
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName);
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LastName);
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Age)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.PhoneNumbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems collections are not supported out of the box as in the above example.

However, by creating a Display Template for class Contact, I can then do this:

```
 @model WebApplication33.Models.Contact
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName);
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LastName);
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Age)
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.PhoneNumbers)
```

Note that I that I did NOT have to use a foreach.